# Run jquery inside sweet alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I have some rows where the user can click and then I run a jQuery function, everything working fine.

As some rows have extra options I decided to load those extra options in a popup window using sweet alert and they should do the same (when the row inside the sweet alert is clicked run same function)

The problem is that the rows inside the sweet alert popup are not calling any function on click. Why can be this?

Can I use sweet alert for this or should I look for other plugin?

This is how I'm calling the jQuery function

```
$('.maincontent').on('click', '.betHandle', function () {
    add(this);
});
```

Comment: is `.maincontent` in the dom during the time that you add the listener?

Comment: maybe the html for the popup lives *outside* the `.maincontent` tree and isn't listening for click. Perhaps loosen your selector?

Comment: try this:

`$('body').on('click', '.betHandle', function () {
    add(this);
});`

Comment: $('body') solution working perfectly, thank you very much :)

Comment: @HectorLandete, thanks, added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is one of two possible reasons it isn't working.

1. as @sweaver2112 has suggested, your `.betHandle` may not be under `.maincontent` in the DOM tree
2. you're adding the listener before `.maincontent` is added to the DOM

In either case, adding the listener to the body will work:

```
$('body').on('click', '.betHandle', function () {
   add(this);
});
```